# New to Objective-C. Trying to pass arguments through a void function, guessing I can't do that?

Tags: objective-c, arguments, void

I am new to Objective C. I am trying to write a void function in my implementation file with arguments however xcode doesn't like that. I did some research and it appears I can't do that.

This is what I am trying to do basically:

```
 -(void)findMilesLeft(float x, float y)
{

    float gallons = x;
    float miles = y;
}
```

I would be calling this findMilesLeft within another void function- I believe I would call it as:

```
 -(void)changeSUV
 {
   [self findMilesLeft(20, 100)];
 }
```

Obviously I have tried this syntax and it didn’t work for me… is there some way I can execute this correctly?

The calculations arent in here obviously but I think the idea is clear.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is:

```
-(void)findMilesLeftWithX:(float)x andY:(float)y
{
    float gallons = x;
    float miles = y;
}
```

And then you call it like that:

```
 -(void)changeSUV
 {
   [self findMilesLeftWithX:20 andY:100];
 }
```

If you didn't do it yet, you should probably read this document :):

[Introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html)

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link. The OP's syntax wasn't even close. A good, much shorter "crash-course" tutorial is on [cocoadevcentral.com](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)